# Too many connection from pinging in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a code to check a network connection like this

```rust
fn network_connection() {
    loop {
        let output = Command::new("ping")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("1")
        .arg("google.com")
        .output()
        .expect("[ ERR ] Failed to execute network check process");

        let network_status = output.status;

        if network_status.success() == false {
            Command::new("init")
            .arg("6");
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(60000));
    }
}

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        network_connection();
    });
...
```

this should ping google every 60 seconds. But when I'm looking at number of request sent to router its like 200 requests per 10 minutes.
Is this spamming more threads than one?
`main()` is running only once.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you have. The `...` seems to imply there's more to this, what else are you doing in main, roughly?

Comment: its long, but its fetching data from site (reqwest) and sleeping for one day thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(SLEEP_TIME_M*60000)); I've checked this part and its executed only once per day

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you are aware that this code never calls `init 6`? It prepares the command but never runs it.

Comment: If you add a `println` each time you run `ping`, you should see how often it's getting called.

Comment: @MarcelKopera I suspect this is a case of the [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A program that sleeps for a day is quite unusual. What are you actually trying to do at the end of all this?